# setValues not working after try/catch statement in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, insert, try-catch, row, setvalue

My Google Apps Script code finds a particular sheet, or creates it if it doesn't exist; it then adds a new row of data underneath the header. When it has to create a new sheet, I want to set up the header line, but it won't work where it's supposed to, and I don't understand why. This code works as is, but you  can see where I want to move my line of code. Any help is appreciated.

```
// for each work order
for (var i = headerCount; i < data.length; i++) {
  var workOrder = data[i][workOrderColumn];
  var inspector = data[i][inspectorColumn];

  // find or create sheet in logSpreadsheet
  var logSheet = logSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(workOrder);
  if(logSheet == null) {

    try {
      logSheet = logSpreadsheet.insertSheet(workOrder);
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      continue;
    }

    //This is where I want this line to be, but it doesn't work here:
    //logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
  }

  // log data
  logSheet.insertRows(1);
  logSheet.setFrozenRows(1);

  //Here, the code works, but it shouldn't be here (it only needs to happen when the sheet is created)
  logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
  logSheet.getRange("A2:B2").setValues([[date, inspector]]);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Does it give an error (Give a description of the error)? Or It doesn't execute that line?

Comment: It doesn't give an error, but when I look at the sheets at the end, A1 and B1 are empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your code not working is because of this set of circumstances.

```
logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
//The above line adds the header to row one
logSheet.insertRows(1);
//The above code inserts a new line at row 1
//That so header line is effectively in row 2 ("A2:B2")
```

So later in the code when you set the value of ("A2:B2") like so

```
logSheet.getRange("A2:B2").setValues([[date, inspector]]);
```

in overwrites the header values.

I would make the following modification

```
logSheet.insertRows(2); // or remove this code
```

Your final code:

```
for (var i = headerCount; i < data.length; i++) {
  var workOrder = data[i][workOrderColumn];
  var inspector = data[i][inspectorColumn];

  // find or create sheet in logSpreadsheet
  var logSheet = logSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(workOrder);
  if(logSheet == null) {

    try {
      logSheet = logSpreadsheet.insertSheet(workOrder);
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
      continue;
    }

    logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
    logSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }

  logSheet.insertRows(2);


  //Here, the code works, but it shouldn't be here (it only needs to happen when the sheet is created)
  //logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
  logSheet.getRange("A2:B2").setValues([[date, inspector]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(logSheet == null) {

    try {
      logSheet = logSpreadsheet.insertSheet('testsheet');
    } catch(e) {
      Logger.log(e);
    }

    // then create the header
    logSheet.setFrozenRows(1);
    logSheet.getRange("A1:B1").setValues([["Date", "Inspector"]]);
  } 
  // then, just add the data starting at row 2. Row 1 is the header
  logSheet.insertRows(2);
  logSheet.getRange("A2:B2").setValues([[Date, Inspector]]);
```

Comment: If the sheet already exists, then the header should have already been populated and that line doesn't need to run, which is why it SHOULD be in the if statement.
I have been testing it by deleting all sheets in the spreadsheet before running the code. When I do this, it creates each sheet as desired but does not set the header values. I even added a Logger.log line before and after that line, and it is in fact getting to the code each time it creates a sheet, and yet at the end the header cells are empty.

Comment: So if the sheet does not exist, create it and add a header. But if it does exist, then just add the data. Correct?

Comment: Correct, that's what it's supposed to do. But as of now it creates the header every time, regardless of whether it was needed.

Comment: You need to insert to row 2 and not 1. Row is is for the header